# trying to expand vlookup to other cells without automatically changing values

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

I am setting up a vlookup to pull product prices from another sheet within the workbook.  The code works for the cell but when i try to expand or copy and past the code into the next row it automatically changes the data table_array value.

=VLOOKUP(B5,Prices!1:65536,3)

Within the code i want the first value, B5 to scale with the row it is in, however the second value needs to remain the same.  How do i go about doing this?  Also is there a way that i can get the cell to remain blank instead of displaying N/A if there isnt a valid part number?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the second part, an IF formula will work fine:

```
=IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(B5,Prices!1:65536,3)),"",VLOOKUP(B5,Prices!1:65536,3)),"")
```

And if I understand correctly the first part have you tried set an absolute value? Something like:

```
    =IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(B$5,Prices!1:65536,3)),"",VLOOKUP(B5,Prices!1:65536,3)),"")
```

Comment: Thats it, thanks!  I am having an issue with adding the if statement as you formated it, the final formula comes up as false.

Answer (score 4):

```
=VLOOKUP(B5,Prices!$1:$65536,3)
```

The `$` lock the range.

For example.

- `$A1` will lock the column to `A` when the formulas is copied other
  locations.
- `A$1` will lock the row
- `$A$1` will lock both the column and the row.

Comment: Accepted solution didn't work for me, but this did. Thanks guitarthrower for posting it.

Answer (score 1):

I can't comment because I do not have enough rep but this will fix `user3716271` 's formula:

```
=IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(B5,Prices!$1:$65536,3)),"", VLOOKUP(B5,Prices!$1:$65536,3))
```

The following formula should solve both problems as well, a little more compact and would use one less `VLOOKUP()`:

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(B5,Prices!$1:$65536,3), "")
```

As `guitarthrower` had said, the `$` before the number is used to lock the range.