# VLOOKUP function works fine for over a thousand cells then stops working

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vlookup, worksheet-function

I am using this lookup on a report that is manually updated with quantities daily. The `VLOOKUP` determines the price of the part by looking it up in another table. The formula is scaling properly but it is returning `#N/A` all of a sudden on later cells (after about 1,500 rows).  The part number is formatted as text, as is the part number on the table it is doing the lookup. I also checked to make sure they were valid part numbers and they do have a price listed on the table.

Here is the `VLOOKUP` code I am using:

```
=IF(ISNA(VLOOKUP(B1889,Prices!$1:$65536,3,FALSE)),"",(VLOOKUP(B1889,Prices!$1:$65536,3,FALSE)))
```

When it gets to the point where it is no longer working, all I see is blank cells (I edited the formula though so that rather than an empty string, it displays `NA` so that I could verify that the formula was running.)

What am I not seeing?

Comment: Did you wait for excel to finish calculating? If you interrupt its calculation, it stops and instead copies the result from a cell higher up, usually the first. Also, you are using this along rows? Why not use `A:C` instead of `1:65536`?

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem in Excel 2007.  Perhaps some of the partnumbers include non-printing characters.  With two cells that should match exactly but do not, what happens if you use the EXACT function to compare them?  Also note pnuts comment; there is no need to include so many cells in the array: 65536 * the number of columns in your worksheet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Largely as already recommended to you [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24831919/trying-to-expand-vlookup-to-other-cells-without-automatically-changing-values), I suggest:

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(B1889,Prices!A:C,3,0),"")
```

It is shorter, easier to understand, is not limited to 65,536 rows, is not limited to ColumnA on Prices and should be faster.